# Why are move semantics for a class containing a std::stringstream causing compiler errors?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, stringstream, move-semantics

How can I make this simple class movable? What I thought was correct just produces a wall of errors...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

class message
{
    public:
        message() = default;

        // Move constructor
        message( message &&other ) :
            stream_( std::move( other.stream_ ) ) // Nope
        {}

        // Move assignment
        message &operator=( message &&other )
        {
            if ( this != &other )
            {
                stream_ = std::move( other.stream_ ); // Nope #2
            }
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        message( const message & ) = delete;
        message &operator=( const message & ) = delete;

        std::stringstream stream_;
        // Other member variables omitted
};

int main()
{
    message m;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x move.cpp -o move
```

... and get a wall of errors about the copy assignments being called for various base classes of the stringstream.

```
move.cpp: In constructor ‘message::message(message&&)’:
move.cpp:12:40: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’
In file included from move.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/sstream:483:11: error: ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/sstream:483:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_iostream<char>::basic_iostream(const std::basic_iostream<char>&)’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:41:0,
                 from move.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:774:11: error: ‘std::basic_iostream<char>::basic_iostream(const std::basic_iostream<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:774:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:57:11: error: ‘std::basic_istream<char>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:57:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’
[SNIP]
```

... This goes on for several pages.

What's wrong with my code?

**Update 1**: Clang 3.0 fails with similar results.
**Update 2**: g++ 4.7 fails also.
**Update 3**: Using the answers as a guide, I found this: [c++11 status in libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) - "27.5    Iostreams base classes: Missing move and swap operations on basic_ios." Curses!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Update

It is required to work according to the C++11/14 standards. GCC 5.0 gets it right, and the below mentioned bug is RESOLVED. Thank you GCC team!

### Original answer

It's a missing feature in gcc (or as Xeo points out libstdc++) as of yet.

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316

According to the standard,

```
typedef basic_stringstream<char> stringstream;
```

and from 27.8.5, there is a public move constructor

```
basic_stringstream(basic_stringstream&& rhs);
```

I can confirm the problem with `gcc 4.7 -std=c++11`, ubuntu 12.04.

```
std::stringstream a;
std::stringstream b=std::move(a);
```

reading the include file `include/std/sstream` I find no move constructor or any mentioning of C++0x or C++11. (compare with `std::string` which does work.)

Adding a (mock) move constructor:

```
basic_stringstream(basic_stringstream&& rhs){}
```

reduces the error to only tree lines, but

```
use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream(
   const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’
```

remains.

### Workaround

Use a `std::unique_ptr<std::stringstream>` instead. Best is to initialize it with `make_unique` which comes with c++14, or take it for example from my blog [cpp11style-no-new-delete](http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/37576903218/cpp11style-no-new-delete) (that is an earlier version, but it will work fine for this purpose).

Comment: gcc bug 54316 has been fixed in gcc 5. I just tested the OP's code with a recent gcc 5, and it does compile.

Answer (score 5):

Clang 3.0 is C++98, Clang 3.1 compiles this just fine (with libc++):

```
~/blargh $ cat t.cpp 
#include <sstream>

int main(){
  auto get_s = []{ return std::stringstream("hi"); };
  auto s = get_s();
}
~/blargh $ clang -v
clang version 3.1 (trunk 152621)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
~/blargh $ clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -pedantic t.cpp 
~/blargh $
```

Your example comples just fine too, so I guess it's libstdc++ that's broken in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely using a bad version of the library. There is no reason why your code should be invalid.

By the way, self-assignment checking assignment operators are bad.

Edit: Curiously, Visual Studio also seems to believe that `basic_stringstream` has no move constructor. All streams *should* be movable in C++11. Perhaps this is a Standard defect, or implementing the move constructor requires a C++11 feature neither yet support. Conceptually, there's no reason why it should fail, but I can't actually find anything to support that.

Comment: Standard doesn't seem to have move ctors for `std::ios_base` and `std::basic_ios` (not that they would need it), in `std::basic_(i|o)stream` they're protected and the derived classes from that are public.

Comment: @Puppy "By the way, self-assignment checking assignment operators are bad." Would you please clarify?